# Use token and call Marketing Cloud APIs from C# via FuelSDK API

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, refresh-token, accesstoken

I would like to call "{authEndPoint}/v2/token" to get the token and then call the REST api to trigger the email. We are using FuelSDK reference file for salesforce connection.

Please  help.

Currently I'm using the code as below which is working fine, but now I would like to use the token value.

[image]

Comment: isn't this covered in the GITHUB for oAuth 2.0? https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thanks a lot @EazyE. Is there an example using this code?